# How do I get a non-null SCOPE_IDENTITY when using INSTEAD OF triggers in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instead of trigger in SQL Server - looses SCOPE_IDENTITY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908257/instead-of-trigger-in-sql-server-looses-scope-identity)

On SQL Server 2008, I have an INSTEAD OF trigger on a view. The `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the trigger is results in `null`. This causes problems with the libraries we're using. How can I control SCOPE_IDENTITY from within my trigger?

This is absolutely needed by Entity Framework in order to get back the ID value of the last inserted row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't - it's SCOPE_IDENTITY() 'cause it returns the identity within the current scope - the trigger is executed in a different scope, so you can't hope to get your hands on the identity with SCOPE_IDENTITY().  @@IDENTITY is what you're after - if the framework can't cope with this then you're out of luck.