# Locking a table while inserting and selecting

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating an asp.net site where a user submits some data which is inserted into table 1, and then I run a query to grab the ID of the entry that was then created from table 1 and then insert that ID into table 2.  The issue is that if someone just happens to submit at the same time I could easily end up with incorrect data.  I assume it is possible to lock table 1 until the data has been inserted into the table 2, but I am unsure how to do it.  Can anyone provide some guidance?  All my code is in a C# Code Behind file.  I read that you could do it with something like the below, but if that works, how is it unlocked?

```
UPDATE table1 WITH (rowlock)
```

Comment: Stored procedures are your friends (with a transaction).

Comment: If you are getting an identity value from the first `INSERT` you should use either `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or an `OUTPUT` clause.  It doesn't require an additional query and gives you "your" answer even if the table is being updated by others.  Do learn about `OUTPUT` as it handles multiple rows, works with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE`, and it provides access to all columns with before and after values (as applicable to the statement).

Comment: And OUTPUT looks simpler to work with than Stored Procedures.  Does anyone know if it is possible to output the OUTPUT in the query to a variable in C# so I can then find that ID in table 2 to update the remaining info?  My SQL knowledge is woefully inadequate I must admit.

Comment: Oh, I read another Question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value) which said that if I use .ExecuteScalar() instead of .ExecuteNonQuery() it will read back the resulting ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample proc that your ADO could call.

```
/*
create table a (id int identity(1,1) primary key, name varchar(max))
create table b (id int identity(1,1) primary key, ParentID int)
GO

create proc Test as
begin
    declare @parentId int
    begin tran
    begin try
        insert into a(name) values('abc')
        select @parentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        select 'ScopeID',@parentID
        insert into b(ParentID) values(@parentid)
        --Uncomment this to see the rollback happen
        --raiserror ('Testing what will happen if an error occurred to make sure rollback works.',
        --       16, -- Severity.
        --       1 -- State.
        --       );
        commit tran
    end try
    begin catch
        rollback tran
    end catch
end
go
*/

truncate table a --TRUNCATE RESET IDENTITY SEED VALUES (UNLIKE DELETE)
truncate table b
exec Test
select * from a
select * from b
```