# How to get the just inserted row in SQL Server stored procedure (without using trigger)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedures that inserts/updates records in some tables. Some columns of those tables have default values or auto-increment. Here's what I have:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp___NewExpense]
  @iCampaignID int,
  @iCategory int,
  @iUserID int,
  @dDate Date,
  @iAmountInINR int,
  @strComments VarChar(200)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO dbo.Tbl_Expenses(iCampaignID, iCategory, dDate, iAmountInINR, strComments)
    VALUES (@iCampaignID, @iCategory, @dDate, @iAmountInINR, @strComments);
  -- How to get the record inserted using the above statement here without using triggers
  -- or another select statement, so that I can assign values to the following variables?

  Declare @justInsertedValue1 type1;
  Declare @justInsertedValue2 type2;
  Declare @justInsertedValue3 type3;

  INSERT INTO dbo.Tbl_SomeOtherTable(col1, col2, col3) 
  VALUES (justInsertedValue1, justInsertedValue2, justInsertedValue3);
END
GO
```

`Tbl_Expenses` has about 9 columns in which two have default values and two have auto-increment set. How can I get the just inserted record just below my `INSERT` statement?

I know that I can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and then a `SELECT`, but a query would probably make it inefficient (am I right?).

(By getting the just inserted record, I mean values of all fields of the just inserted record)

**Edit**: I haven't specified values for all the fields in my `INSERT` statement. I want to get those values inserted automatically by SQL Server due to DEFAULT/AUTO INCREMENT constraints also.

Comment: you just inserted that data using variables. Why do you need to fetch the data again? the same data is STILL in those variables.

Comment: @Marc: I haven't specified values for all the fields in the insert statement.

Comment: You should be able to use `OUTPUT` to get the values you are looking for (if your version of SQL Server supports it).

Comment: If you haven't specify the values that columns would be null or default values.

Comment: You should be able to determine the values anyway.  The columns will be null, the default value, or can be gotten by SCOPE_IDENTITY().  No need to select from the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use an INSERT statement's OUTPUT clause to get the identity value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx). You can even combine both `inserts` into one composite:

```
create table T1 (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,ColA varchar(10) not null)
create table T2 (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,T1ID int not null,ColB varchar(10) not null)


--Look ma! no local variables at all
insert into T2 (T1ID,ColB)
select t1.ID,'def'
from (
    insert into T1(ColA)
    output inserted.ID
    values ('abc')
    ) t1

select * from T1
select * from T2
```

Results:

```
ID          ColA
----------- ----------
1           abc

ID          T1ID        ColB
----------- ----------- ----------
1           1           def
```

Comment: +1 I'm constantly amazed at how few SQL Server developers apparently know about the `OUTPUT` clause ... a true **gem** !

Comment: One to be careful of - depending on the SQL version, the OUTPUT clause doesn't work on a table with triggers, You need to use OUTPUT INTO instead (to a table variable)