# Get the auto-increment value right after an inset

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working on a online store. I keep the added items in the cookies and at the time of check out, I place the order in the database. In my DB I have two tables `orders`, `orderItems`.

```
Order:
[Order_Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Customer_Id] INT --FK--
....

OrderItems
[Order_Id] INT --FK to Order--
[Item_Id] INT --FK to Item table--
```

When I place the order first in order table I need the `Order_Id` to be able to properly place items for the order. I know that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` would give me the last identity in the table but **I think this might cause some concurrency problem**. I'm using EF6 so I'm not sure even if I can use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` but even though I can I'm still concerned about the concurrency problems.
What I wanna know is how to get the auto-incremented identity right after the insert ?

I'm using EF 6 as ORM and the website is written in ASP.NET MVC C#.

Comment: Within a stored procedure one would use the OUTPUT clause as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value

Comment: What sort of concurrency problems do you think scope_identity has? I've used it quite a bit and do not find it wanting...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a column in your order table and store the date and time of when the insertion takes place to milliseconds. Assign this value to a local variable before performing the insert and try to query that back. This solves your concurrency problem.