# Reading last inserted UID from database using SQL Command

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I've got two table as per diagram below and have some sample data on the table as well.

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve in my project is as follows. I've got 4 windows form in my project. First form with two buttons

[image]

`New User` has a click event of-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewUser nu = new NewUser();
    nu.Show();

}
```

Upon click, it brings up NewUser form
[image]

The plan is to add data here for `Users Table` then click `Save and Proceed`(right now I'm using the default `Save` button on NAV bar) which will take the `UID` from `Users Table` and add it under column `UID` (which is foreign key in `Address Table`) and open form `FormAddress` where I can enter the data for the table.[image]

Click event for `Save and Proceed` is--

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormAddress ad = new FormAddress();
    ad.Show();
    getdata();
}
```

Upon research I've learned that I need to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the value of `UID` from last data insertion and carry it over to next form. So I've created a method `getdata()` as follows and added it under button event `Save and Proceed`

The code I tried is

```
private void getdata()
{

    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"mycon string is here;" + "Initial Catalog=Stack;Integrated Security=YES");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader reader;

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

    sqlConnection1.Open();

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

    cmd.CommandText = "SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

    sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

I Just can't get my head to work and figure out how to get the `SCOPE_IDENTITY`and make it work. Please ask me before I get down-voted. I'll respond and reply/make changes as necessary. And I have zipped the project and SQL server file [HERE](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9BC526B36E7CAB64!5711&authkey=!AEW-ylablkd6mEg&ithint=file%2Czip) if anyone wants to download them to run and test. I've used SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the last identity created in the scope of the correct batch, in other words the id of the record that was just inserted. You are not inserting a record, so it is not applicable. What do you actually want? The highest current `UID`? `SELECT MAX(UID) FROM Users`

Comment: @BenRobinson In second form `NewUser` I am inserting a new row. What I want is the UID to carry over automatically to next form `Address` where I can carry on filling the data under the same UID as `Users Table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't just done an `INSERT` on that connection, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is undefined. You can't display the new `IDENTITY` value *in advance*, because most databases are multi-user - thus this value *cannot be known* until you actually do the `INSERT`. It would be misleading to display a "probably going to be this" value - the user might write it down or use it in communication with someone, for example. You can *only* show this value *after* it exists in the database.

But: when you an `INSERT`, you can then *immediately* simply query `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to see what the value was. More recently, [you can use the `OUTPUT` clause of an `INSERT` operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value) - simpler, only one set of SQL operations, and it works with multiple rows : all wins.

Comment: I am inserting a new row in second form and saving it using the Save button on the nav bar

Comment: @envyM6 then... just `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the `INSERT`.

Comment: Mark I'm inserting the data using the grid view. not programmatically.

Comment: @envyM6 re `getdata()` - since that is a separate connection (which, incidentally, should probably be using a `using` statement), it has no access to the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` you want; that is contextual *to the individual connection*. You could re-query the underlying data and replace it, perhaps.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to enter the data programmatically and include `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` ?

Comment: @envyM6 I'm merely observing that if you use binding tools extensively, you need to live with the limitations of those tools. If you can do that: *great*. If you can simply re-query the data after the insert: *good enough*. Refactoring it and re-writing all the data access after-the-fact is not trivial.

Comment: Man I need a Jargon Buster!

Answer (score 1):

Get the ID with this line:

`cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";`

Comment: How can I store it in a variable?

Comment: @envyM6 `int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`, but again: this won't help unless you are a: on the same connection (you aren't), and b: you haven't done anything else on that connection

Comment: The problem with different connection can be solved easily. Simply, use one connection for whole session (after Login) and not Open/Close it for each query - use the same connection for the Identity query. I hope editor windows can work in this way, too. I think this is the better method for Desktop applications instead of closing connection for each query. Look that MS SQL Studio works in the same way. Even with 'sp_who' you can see your app in the list.