# T-SQL Select, manipulate, and re-insert via stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dictionary

The short version is I'm trying to map from a flat table to a new set of tables with a stored procedure.

The long version: I want to `SELECT` records from an existing table, and then for each record `INSERT` into a new set of tables (most columns will go into one table, but some will go to others and be related back to this new table).

I'm a little new to stored procedures and T-SQL. I haven't been able to find anything particularly clear on this subject.

It would appear I want to something along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyNewTable] (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT
        OldCol1, OldCol2, OldCol3 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[MyOldTable]
```

But I'm uncertain how to get that to save related records since I'm splitting it into multiple tables. I'll also need to manipulate some of the data from the old columns before it will fit into the new columns.

Thanks

**Example data**

**MyOldTable**

```
Id  | Year | Make | Model   | Customer Name
572 | 2001 | Ford | Focus   | Bobby Smith
782 | 2015 | Ford | Mustang | Bobby Smith
```

Into (with no worries about duplicate customers or retaining old Ids):

**MyNewCarTable**

```
Id | Year | Make | Model
1  | 2001 | Ford | Focus 
2  | 2015 | Ford | Mustang
```

**MyNewCustomerTable**

```
Id | FirstName | LastName | CarId
1  | Bobby     | Smith    | 1
2  | Bobby     | Smith    | 2
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desired outcome ?

Comment: @GuidoG Sure one moment.

Comment: I think the user is trying to add some data,so not worthy of downvotes

Comment: @GuidoG There we go!

Comment: what is unique key or combination in your old table?

Comment: Oh man, separating the `Customer Name` to `FirstName` and `LastName` is reaaaaaally not trivial

Comment: @techspider updated. There's existing Ids that we don't care about, as new Ids will be assigned as records are inserted.

Comment: @Lamak I can work out how to do the actual manipulation, just not sure where that should happen

Comment: Are you sure your customer name always has First Name and Last Name only separated by space? Are you sure no middle names anywhere?

Comment: use the output clause of the insert into MyNewCarTable to insert into MyNewCustomerTable using the identity values from the INSERTED virtual table, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value .

Comment: @techspider This is example only my actual tables are much more beastly (the origin table has like 35 columns) but yes, I will be able to manage the manipulations themselves. They're pretty straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you have your OldTable Id to preserve in new table till you process data.

I assume you create an `Identity` column `Id` on your `MyNewCarTable`

```
INSERT INTO MyNewCarTable (OldId, Year, Make, Model)
SELECT Id, Year, Make, Model FROM MyOldTable
```

Then, join the new table and above table to insert into your second table.  I assume your `MyNewCustomerTable` also has `Id` column with `Identity` enabled.

```
INSERT INTO MyNewCustomerTable (CustomerName, CarId)
SELECT CustomerName, new.Id 
FROM MyOldTable old
JOIN MyNewCarTable new ON old.Id = new.OldId
```

> Note: I have not applied Split of Customer Name to First Name and
>   Last Name as I was unsure about existing data.

If you don't want your `OldId` in `MyNewCarTable`, you can `DELETE` it

```
ALTER TABLE MyNewCarTable DROP COLUMN OldId
```

Comment: This gets me off to a great start, thanks! Once I get it working I'll accept, might take me a bit though.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a step in your normalization. You do not need to duplicate your customer information per vehicle. You need three tables for 4th Normal form. This will reduce storage size and more importantly allow an update to the customer data to take place in one location.

**Customer**
CustomerID 
FirstName 
LastName

**Car** 
CarID
Make
Model
Year

**CustomerCar**
CustomerCarID 
CarID 
CustomerID 
DatePurchaed

This way you can have multiple owners per car, multiple cars per owner and only one record needs to be updated per car and or customer...4th Normal Form.

Answer (score -1):

If I am reading this correctly, you want to take each row from table 1, and create a new record into table A using some of that row data, and then data from the same original row into Table B, Table C but referencing back to Table A again?

If that's the case, you will create TableA with an Identity and make thats the PK.

Insert the required column data into that table and use the @IDENTITY to retrieve the last identity value, then you will insert the remaining data from the original table into the other tables, TableB, TableC, etc. and use the identity you retrieved from TableA as the FK in the other tables.

By Example:

Table 1 has columns col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
Table A has TabAID, col1, col2
Table B has TabBID, TabAID, col3
TableC has TabCID, TabAID, col4

When the first row is read, the values for col1 & col2 are inserted into TableA.
The Identity is captured from that row inserted, and then value for col3 AND the identity are entered into TableB, and then value for col4 AND the identity are entered into TableC.

This is a standard data migration technique for normalizing data.

Hope this assists,