# Retrieve the Inserted ID after executing ExecuteSqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I would like to retrieve the inserted ID after executing this command:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table_Ressources (IdTypeRessource, IdSociete, IdTypeFormatIntitule_UR)Values (1,1,1);
```

How should I do it please?

Comment: Here the primary key colum is identity column and it's none of the columns specified here in question?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use OUTPUT with ExecuteScalar to return the ID of the record INSERTED (or even updated).

```
INSERT INTO Table_Ressources (IdTypeRessource, IdSociete, IdTypeFormatIntitule_UR) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
VALUES (1,1,1);
```

The statement will return the ID of the inserted record.

Some reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

[How do I use an INSERT statement's OUTPUT clause to get the identity value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to the command, and look at the return value of `ExecuteSqlCommand`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "**ExecuteScalar**" instead of "**ExecuteSqlCommand**".
The ExecuteScalar does what you need as explained here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx