# Azure Stored Procedure does not return inserted ID to ASP.NET App

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure defined on Azure SQL Database Server.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertGameSession]
    (@finished BIT,
     @createUser VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[game_Session]
           ([finished]
           ,[createUser]
           ,[createDate]
           ,[changeUser]
           ,[changeDate])
     VALUES
           (@finished
           ,@createUser
           ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
           ,@createUser
           ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
     RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Called from ASP.NET Application through a data adapter.

- Command Type : Stored Procedure
- Execution Mode : NonQuery
- Modifier : Public
- Parameters :

  - `@RETURN_VALUE`, ColumnName = id, Direction = ReturnValue, SourceColumn = id
  - `@finished`, ColumnName = finished, Direction = Input, SourceColumn = finished
  - `@createUser`, ColumnName = createUser, Direction = Input, SourceColumn = createUser

If the stored procedure is called from DBMS, a correct id is being returned.

If the stored procedure is called from ASP.NET web application, return value is suddenly 0 or null.

What should I do to get the same result in ASP.NET?

Comment: Since your stored procedure is **returning** something (the newly inserted Id), you must call is using `ExecuteScalar` - not `ExecuteNonQuery` ....

Comment: @marc_s thank you for your suggestion. So I changed it to `ExecuteScalar` but now my return value is an Object which is always null. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Parameter direction ReturnValue is unrelated to whether you use `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteNonQuery` because it is not part of the result set. Show your code. Also consider [using `OUTPUT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value) in the query instead of `RETURN` which is meant to communicate status, not data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without seeing the calling code, but you should never return data using the return value of a stored procedure.  That's intended to indicate success or failure, and only when called from TSQL.  Instead return data using an output parameter or a resultset.  So

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertGameSession]
    (@finished BIT,
     @createUser VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[game_Session]
           ([finished]
           ,[createUser]
           ,[createDate]
           ,[changeUser]
           ,[changeDate])
     VALUES
           (@finished
           ,@createUser
           ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
           ,@createUser
           ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
     SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() Id;
END
```

And then from client code retrieve the new ID with ExecuteScalar(), or ExecuteReader().