# How can i get updated identies from mssql table?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to track the updated rows in my database by saving them in another table. I have a code like this:

`"UPDATE Table1 SET [HastaSN] = @HastaSN WHERE Id = @Id; INSERT INTO Changes ([TableName],[Ids]) VALUES ('Table1 ', (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('[Table1 ]')))"`

I always get a table when I try to update a few rows in my database :

```
  TableName  Ids
    Table1  56697
    Table1  56697
    Table1  56697
```

It's just showing me the last ID of the table. Not every ID number. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an INSERT statement's OUTPUT clause to get the identity value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value)

Comment: It is not related to this insert. This is about the update. And the OUTPUT.UPDATED clause in mssql does not work, i think.

Comment: Don't you already know the ID from the variable `@ID` which you use in your `WHERE`? The value of an `IDENTITY` doesnt change when. You `UPDATE` the row.

Comment: I want to save IDs to another table automatically. Thus, other computers can monitor data changes.

Comment: @ismailakarim if you check the docs you'll see that [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  works in  INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and MERGE

Comment: If you want to save IDs "automatically", you may be looking for an `UPDATE` trigger. That will have the affected rows in the `deleted` and `inserted` pseudo-tables.

Comment: Ok. I ll look again. Thank you all.

Comment: @ismailakarim if you *already* know that ID why don't you use it? In any case, the duplicate and the OUTPUT doc page shows how to write original and changed values to another table. If you want that to happen without modifying the INSERT statements use a trigger or the [system versioned tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) introduced in SQL Server 2016

Comment: How can i do that UPDATE trigger? Like OUTPUT.INSERTED?

Comment: @ismailakarim that's described in the docs. Few people can remember every statement's syntax, we all open the docs. Googling for `t-sql create trigger` returns the doc page [CREATE TRIGGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) at the top

Comment: Ok. I understood a bit. I have to examine more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OUTPUT clause should work for you.  Here's an example of using it.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    SomeText VARCHAR(100)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #IDTable;
CREATE TABLE #IDTable (ID INT);

INSERT INTO #t (SomeText)
VALUES ('Hello'),
       ('World');

UPDATE #t
SET SomeText = 'World!'
OUTPUT Inserted.ID
INTO #IDTable
WHERE ID = 2;

SELECT ID FROM #IDTable;
```

In your example it might look something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET [HastaSN] = @HastaSN
OUTPUT 'Table1', Inserted.Id
INTO Changes
WHERE Id = @Id
```

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I have to use again 'Inserted.ID'. This can solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: But i'm trying to put Table1.ID's in Changes table. This already placing. Sorry.