# Sql Scope_Identity() return Null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing this issue that my stored proc always return NULL though i have set my @output variable as well.I want to get last inserted scope Id from the table.

can someone help me where i have got wrong?

```
   ALTER PROC spAddOrUpdateMember

     @pMemberId INT =  0 ,
     @pFirstName VARCHAR(50) = 'aa',
     @pLastName VARCHAR(50)='aa' ,
     @pMemberCode VARCHAR(15) = '12312',
     @pDOB DATE = '03/10/2019',
     @pGrade INT = 2 , 
     @pCNIC VARCHAR(14) = '3423434',
     @pFatherName VARCHAR(50) = 'asdasd' , 
     @pCurrentAddress VARCHAR(MAX) = 'asds' , 
     @pPermanentAddress VARCHAR(MAX) = 'fgdf',
     @pEmploymentAddress VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ytuyu' ,
     @pNationality INT =2
     @output int = 0 output    

AS

    BEGIN   
            IF @pMemberId > 0
                BEGIN
                        ---UPDATE ME
                            UPDATE [dbo].[QC_Member_Profile]
                           SET 
                              [FirstName] = @pFirstName
                              ,[LastName] = @pLastName
                              ,[DOB] = @pDOB
                              ,[CNIC] = @pCNIC
                              ,[FatherName] = @pFatherName
                              ,[CurrentAddress] = @pCurrentAddress
                              ,[PermanentAddress] = @pPermanentAddress
                              ,[Nationality] = @pNationality
                              ,[MemberTypeId] =@pMemberTypeId

                         WHERE MemberId  = @pMemberId

                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    ---INSERT ME
                    INSERT INTO QC_Member_Profile VALUES(
                                                         dbo.PIdentityKey(0),
                                                         @pFirstName,
                                                         @pLastName,
                                                         @pDOB,
                                                         @pCNIC,
                                                         @pFatherName,
                                                         @pCurrentAddress,
                                                         @pPermanentAddress,
                                                         @pNationality,
                                                        )

                                set @output  = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
                                SELECT @output  =  SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                                select @output
                END


    END
```

Comment: Don't use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` at all.  us the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: But @output is output variable which need to set as Scope_Ident?

Comment: Not the `OUTPUT` parameter type, naveed, the `OUTPUT` clause: [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If you need to get pass that back via the `OUTPUT` parameter type use the `OUTPUT` clause the put the values in a table variable and then set the values of your parameters from there.

Comment: i have never use Output as Clause .. can you update my code with your answer ??

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've guessed the name of your ID column, however, this should work. You'll need to amend the name of your ID column if it isn't called `MemberID` or if it doesn't have the data type `int`:

```
ALTER PROC spAddOrUpdateMember @pMemberId int = 0,
                               @pFirstName varchar(50) = 'aa',
                               @pLastName varchar(50) = 'aa',
                               @pMemberCode varchar(15) = '12312',
                               @pDOB date = '03/10/2019',
                               @pGrade int = 2,
                               @pCNIC varchar(14) = '3423434',
                               @pFatherName varchar(50) = 'asdasd',
                               @pCurrentAddress varchar(MAX) = 'asds',
                               @pPermanentAddress varchar(MAX) = 'fgdf',
                               @pEmploymentAddress varchar(MAX) = 'ytuyu',
                               @pNationality int = 2,
                               @output int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @pMemberId > 0
    BEGIN

        UPDATE [dbo].[QC_Member_Profile]
        SET [FirstName] = @pFirstName,
            [LastName] = @pLastName,
            [DOB] = @pDOB,
            [CNIC] = @pCNIC,
            [FatherName] = @pFatherName,
            [CurrentAddress] = @pCurrentAddress,
            [PermanentAddress] = @pPermanentAddress,
            [Nationality] = @pNationality,
            [MemberTypeId] = @pMemberTypeId
        WHERE MemberId = @pMemberId;

    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @ins table (OutputID int);
        INSERT INTO QC_Member_Profile
        OUTPUT Inserted.MemberID --guessed name
        INTO @Ins
        VALUES (dbo.PIdentityKey(0), @pFirstName, @pLastName, @pDOB, @pCNIC, @pFatherName, @pCurrentAddress, @pPermanentAddress, @pNationality);

        SELECT @output = OutputID 
        FROM @ins;
        SELECT @Output;
    END;


END;
```

I've also fixed the syntax errors that were in your original question.

Comment: This solved my issue :) Thanks.. but whats wrong with SCOPE_IDENTITY ?

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will be affected by things like triggers, other inserts in the same session, can only cater for one row, etc, etc. @naveedahmed . The fact that you were getting the value `NULL` also shows that there's something happening "under the hood" that is changing the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` before your `SET @output  = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` and `SELECT @output  = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` statements (not sure why you're setting it twice). The OUTPUT Clause doesn't suffer these problems/features.