# How can i get the last id from the database in C#

Tags: sql-server, c#-2.0

I have tried using the `SELECT` query to get the last id from the database, i.e. `SELECT LAST_INSERT_id FROM studentdetails` but it is not working for me.

I really need help!

Please what query can I use to get the last id from the database?

```cs
string me = dtba.ConnectionString();

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(me);

string selectquery = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_id FROM studentdetails";
SqlCommand selectcmd = new SqlCommand(selectquery, connection);

selectcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", registrationNo.Text);

try
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = selectcmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {                    
        registrationNo.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
    }

    if (registrationNo.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SORRY ID HAS NOT BEEN READ");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("REGISTRATION NUMBER IS CORRECT");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value

Comment: related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MySQL**

It's:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id FROM studentdetails
```

rather than

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_id FROM studentdetails
```

This is because `LAST_INSERT_ID` is a function, not a column name. This is assuming you are using MySQL.

**SQL Server**

If you are using SQL Server, use this:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id FROM studentdetails
```

Please note that the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function can only be used right after an `INSERT`, and it will only work if the table that you've inserted a row into has an `IDENTITY` (auto-incrementing) column.

Comment: its kind of working, but it is showing an exception: "'LAST_INSERT_ID' is ot a recongnised built-in function name."

Comment: Is this actually MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server, that is?

Comment: I have amended my answer for you.

Comment: "Sql" is an ambiguous term.  Please refer to the products as "MySql" or "Sql Server" or less ambiguous "Microsoft Sql Server".  Using un-ambiguous terms will help your path to development tremendously.

Comment: @SMARTG.: the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function can only be used *right after* an `INSERT`, and it will **only** work if your table that you've inserted a row into has an `IDENTITY` (auto-incrementing) column

Comment: The obseration by @marc_s is very important to I'm copying that into the answer.

Comment: Just a slight correction; you do not want FROM anything with SCOPE_IDENTITY() or LAST_INSERT_ID(). Neither care what table you are specifying; including FROM just gets you a result set with the same number over and over again, as many times are there are rows in the table specified.

Comment: @SMARTG. SCOPE_IDENTITY() and last_insert_id() are specifically for retrieving the identity/auto-increment id of a row code has just inserted; for "any table" MSSQL has `IDENT_CURRENT('table_name')`.