# SQL Server stored procedure not returning correct output value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a stored procedure for an insert, and for some reason when I test it, it's giving me the wrong output value.

This is the stored procedure that's working correctly:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddSponsor
    @intSponsorID AS INTEGER OUTPUT,
    @strFirstName AS VARCHAR(50),
    @strLastName AS VARCHAR(50),
    @strStreetAddress AS VARCHAR(50),
    @strCity AS VARCHAR(50),
    @strState AS VARCHAR(50),
    @strZip AS VARCHAR(50),
    @strPhoneNumber AS VARCHAR(50),
    @strEmail AS VARCHAR(50),
AS 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON   --Terminate and rollback transaction on error

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TSponsors WITH (TABLOCKX) (strFirstName, strLastName, strStreetAddress, strCity, strState, strZip, strPhoneNumber, strEmail)
    VALUES (@strFirstName, @strLastName, @strStreetAddress, @strCity, @strState, @strZip, @strPhoneNumber, @strEmail)

    SELECT @intSponsorID = MAX(intSponsorID) FROM TSponsors

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO

-- Test
DECLARE @intSponsorID AS INTEGER = 0
EXECUTE uspAddSponsor @intSponsorID OUTPUT, 'Tofu', 'The Cat', '3000 Maple Butter Ln', 'Honolulu', 'Hawaii', '96815', '808-545-8887', 'meow@aol.com'
PRINT 'Sponsor ID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @intSponsorID)
```

The output correctly prints Sponsor ID = 1.

However, this stored procedure here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddEventGolferSponsor
    @intGolferEventYearSponsorID AS INTEGER OUTPUT,
    @intGolferID AS INTEGER,
    @intEventYearID AS INTEGER,
    @intSponsorID AS INTEGER,
    @monPledgeAmount AS MONEY,
    @intSponsorTypeID AS INTEGER,
    @intPaymentTypeID AS INTEGER,
    @blnPaid AS BIT
AS
    SET XACT_ABORT ON --Terminate and rollback transaction on error

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TGolferEventYearSponsors WITH (TABLOCKX) (intGolferID, intEventYearID, intSponsorID, monPledgeAmount, intSponsorTypeID, intPaymentTypeID, blnPaid)
    VALUES (@intGolferID, @intEventYearID, @intSponsorID, @monPledgeAmount, @intSponsorTypeID, @intPaymentTypeID, @blnPaid)

    SELECT @intGolferEventYearSponsorID = MAX(@intGolferEventYearSponsorID) 
    FROM TGolferEventYearSponsors

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO

--Test
DECLARE @intGolferEventYearSponsorID AS INTEGER = 0
EXECUTE uspAddEventGolferSponsor @intGolferEventYearSponsorID OUTPUT, 1, 1, 1, 25, 2, 2, 1
PRINT 'Event Golfer Sponsor ID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @intGolferEventYearSponsorID)
 
SELECT * FROM TGolferEventYearSponsors
```

is incorrectly printing

```
GolferEventYearSponsorID = 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any rows on TGolferEventYearSponsors table?

Comment: Yes, it successfully added the new row, and the ID is 1, which is correct, but it's printing 0 for some reason.

Comment: Why would you go after `MAX()` (which requires an additional transactionally consistent and isolated read of the table) instead of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (which doesn't)?

Comment: @jennifer jonas what do you expect @ intGolferEventYearSponsor to return? I posted an answer to resolve getting 0 back but I don't know exactly what you want this output parameter to return.

Comment: I hope you don't think `Max(ID)` gets the ID of the inserted row because it doesn't. Use the [`OUTPUT` clause of the `INSERT` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/) which is designed to do exactly that.

Comment: I was expecting it to return the primary key of the row added, which is 1. I have never heard of scope_identity but will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, use the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/) which has been part of SQL for decades.

Comment: What is the primary key column name? @jennifer jonas

Comment: The PK column name is intGolferEventYearSponsorID

Comment: @Dour High Archa I agree there is more efficient ways to get the identity value but the question is about the OUTPUT parameter not how to get an identity column value after insert. I provided and answer to resolve the error where the OUTPUT parameter was being assigned, keeping original query design from the author and explained why 0 was printed.

Comment: @DourHighArch Why do you suggest the OUTPUT clause is superior to SCOPE_IDENTITY() when inserting a single row?

Comment: @Aaron because it works when you insert more than one row so you don't have to convince yourself you can only insert one row and later find you were wrong.

Comment: @DourHighArch Context. The OP's stored procedure inserts a single row based on single, scalar input parameters. Should a single adult not buy a sedan because they might someday have a family and obviously a minivan is a better choice so that later when they have a family they don't regret the choice of buying a sedan? Using the OUTPUT clause to move SCOPE_IDENTITY() to an output parameter requires outputting into a table variable and then selecting from the table variable. That's fun, but it seems like a lot of scaffolding for no benefit in the OP's case.

Comment: @Dour High Arch that makes complete sense but also consider the way the sproc is currently written it would only be inserting a single row at a time. OUTPUT would make more sense if a UDT was passed in to allow multiple rows to be inserted in one execution.

Comment: @vvv4d it's not just “more efficient” it works when you insert more than one row, when rows are inserted in parallel, when IDs are allowed to be negative, when IDs have been reserved and inserted later, or are determined programmatically, or you insert specific IDs. Using `Max(ID)` works when you try it in Management Studio but creates extremely pernicious bugs in production.

Comment: @DourHighArch Please post an answer with a _working example_ of your superior solution, explain why it's better, and let the OP decide if the complexity is worth it. Maybe you can demonstrate a scenario where `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` fails in parallel, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the stored procedure `uspAddEventGolferSponsor`

Select the `max` **intGolferEventYearSponsorID** or some other column instead of the variable **@intGolferEventYearSponsorID**

I think you accidentally included the **@** within the `max()` function.

`SELECT @intGolferEventYearSponsorID = MAX(intGolferEventYearSponsorID) FROM TGolferEventYearSponsors`

It's printing 0 because you were setting `@intGolferEventYearSponsorID` to itself the max of `@intGolferEventYearSponsorID` that was not changed after you initially declared it and set the value to 0.

Comment: @jennifer this doesn't return “the primary key of the row added” which you asked for, it returns the largest ID value, which might be the same thing when you test but won't be forever.

Comment: The problem identified in the question (that the output parameter contains 0 instead of 1) is definitely because the `MAX()` was being applied to a scalar variable instead of a column. But using `MAX()` at all is still a problem. In this specific case, where you can only ever be inserting a single row, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (or, if you like write a whole bunch of extra code for nothing, the `OUTPUT` clause).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand I agree `SELECT @intGolferEventYearSponsorID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` would be superior to using `max`. Unless your in a strange edge case scenario where `set identity insert on` is used to insert an explicit identity value, that may have already been used or would be used in the future, then the result from `max` will match what `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns.