# Capturing the SELECTed value from a trigger

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm inserting values into a view which has an INSTEAD OF trigger to insert/update various other tables. The final line of the trigger is

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

which means that when I select `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` myself after the insert so I can use the just inserted identity value I get a NULL value.

If I understand it correctly, this is because there is no identity value associated with the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` that was just called.

Is there a way to get the SELECT value from the trigger? Changing the trigger is not really an option due to other dependencies on its current behaviour.

I could do it with a temp table and executing the insert as dynamic SQL but that seems like a horribly hacky way to do it:

```
DECLARE @scopeid INT
CREATE TABLE #temp(id int)
INSERT INTO #temp EXEC ('INSERT INTO myView(somecolumns) VALUES (somevalues)')
SELECT @scopeid = TOP 1 id FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Surely there's a neater way than this?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908257/instead-of-trigger-in-sql-server-loses-scope-identity)

Comment: That link suggests using @@IDENTITY, but wouldn't that cause a race condition if something else happens to be inserting to a different table at the same time?

Comment: There's another solution under the link I gave to use OUTPUT clause. Have you tried that?